# How to add to %ENV more variables for one parrticular perl script

Tags: perl

I want to  add more variables to %ENV visible only for one script
Is it correct or we have some other ways?
    $ENV{IM_ROOT} =  $TC_ROOT;
    $ENV{IM_DATA} |= $TC_DATA;

Comment: Be aware of: The hash %ENV contains your current environment. Setting a value in ENV changes the environment for any child processes you subsequently fork() off. From [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could assign as a hash, kind of an append:

```
# cat fooenv.pl && ./fooenv.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

%ENV = ( %ENV,
  'XX' => 'foovar',
  'YY' => 'barvar'
);

foreach $key (grep(/XX|YY/,keys(%ENV))){
  printf "key=$key=%s\n",$ENV{$key};
}
key=YY=barvar
key=XX=foovar
```